# Manipulating child image from container within background image

Tags: flutter, image, background, containers, resize

I am trying to manipulate the size and position of an image which are over a background image. I have tried to set the height and width of a child image but it does not shrink.

What I want is to shrink the size of a child image("Neighbor") and give a position to 1/4 of the full screen from the top.

Any suggestions of what I can do?

Here is how my current app looks like:

[image: Here is how my current app looks like]

Here is the code:

[image: Here is the code]

Comment: please do not send screenshot of codes. post code as text code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/black-rocks.jpeg',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/neighbor-name-and-logo.png',
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It was what I have wanted to scale down that image! Could you be willingly tell us how that works under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use Fractionaloffset or FractionallySizedBox

   ...
   Container(
   color: Colors.blue[200],
   alignment: FractionalOffset(0.7, 0.6),
   child: FractionallySizedBox(
   widthFactor: 0.1,
   heightFactor: 1/3,
   child: Container(color: Colors.red[900])
   ),
   ),
   ...

Or
you can use https://velocityx.dev/docs/padding Plugin and give the top padding in percentage or
context.screenHeight*0.4

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to alignment with these method!